# Use R to Calculate time difference between rows in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table for which I want to calculate the time difference between two specific rows (1 and 4) and then add the calculated value to a new column. Original table:

```
Name                   Type
Main processing time   2015-12-26 13:36:40
AA                     AA data
bb                     bb data
End processing Time    2015-12-26 14:36:40
```

End result

```
Name                   Type
Main processing time   2015-12-26 13:36:40
AA                     AA data
bb                     bb data
End processing Time    2015-12-26 14:36:40
Total time             1 hour
```

Data:

```
dt <- structure(list(
Name = c("Main processing time", "AA", "bb", "End processing Time"), 
Type = c("2015-12-26 13:36:40", "AA data", "bb data", "2015-12-26 
14:36:40")),.Names = c("Name", "Type"), row.names = 1:4, class = 
"data.table")
```

Any suggestions on how to do this using data.table?  I could only find other solutions which were for consecutive rows.  Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Does your data only have 4 rows, or is this repeated many times?

Comment: It is repeated multiple times, the actual data set has about a 1000 rows

Comment: Can you update with a slightly bigger example, say with 8/12/16 rows? Also, do you have any control over the structure of the `data.table`? Why are 'times' mixed in with 'data types' in the `Type` column?

Comment: Would it make sense to have your data in columns? Column operators are more natural to `data.table`. You'd use `as.Date` on date columns and subtract for days.